# Pyspark unlist rdd

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have a rdd with the following structure: **[int,[list]]**

```
In [109]: rdd_dummies2.take(2)
[[0, [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]],
 [1, [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]]
```

I would like to have another rdd with the int and the list in the same list.
I mean, something like this:

```
[[0,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
[1,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

I tried this:

```
In [110]: rdd_dummies2 = rdd_dummies.flatMap(lambda x: x)
In [112]: rdd_dummies2.take(2)
Out[112]: [0, [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

but it doesn't return what I want.

Does anybody know how to use .map() or .flatMap() properly to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to map over the `rdd` and prepend the first element to the list:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([[0, [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]], [1, [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]])

rdd.map(lambda x: [x[0]] + x[1]).collect()
# [[0, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], 
#  [1, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Comment: I've just used it on my progam and it works. Thank you :)